# error:invalid_client - IdentityServer Flow.ClientCredential

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, identityserver3, openid-connect, clientid

I'm having a Client in my IdentityServer3

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Client Credentials Flow Client with Client Certificate",
    ClientId = "certclient",

    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
    {
        new Secret
        {
            Value = "61B754C541BBCFC6A45A9E9EC5E47D8702B78C29",
            Type = Constants.SecretTypes.X509CertificateThumbprint,
        }
    },

    Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        "read",
        "write"
    },
}
```

I hosted the Token Service in my local IIS and I tried to ping the Token using Postman, but it given an error `{"error":"invalid_client"}`

```
Host URL: 
    https://localhost:5775/core/connect/token
Header: 
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization:Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
Body:
    grant_type=client_credentials
    &cliend_id=certclient
    &client_secret=61B754C541BBCFC6A45A9E9EC5E47D8702B78C29
```

[image]

> Note: I'm using pure IdentityServer3 package not Thinktecture

Comment: I think you need to send the values as x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @Jinish - I given that in `Header`

Comment: @Jinish - I added a similar question but it gives a different error : `invalid_scope` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767613/errorinvalid-scope-ideneityserver-flow-clientcredential

Comment: Where are you providing the scope you are requesting in the request?

Comment: so something like: grant_type=client_credentials&cliend_id=certclient    &client_secret=61B754C541BBCFC6A45A9E9EC5E47D8702B78C29&scope=read

Comment: @Jinish - I tried the same, but I got an error in both the questions...